# devexpress aspxgridview - setting label with page number

Tags: asp.net-3.5, label, aspxgridview

I am using devexpress aspxgridview in asp.net 3.5 web application.

on pageload, I have a label control on top of the page whose text for example is "abc".

I am trying to set the value of the label with the page number selected by the user from the grid using onpageindexchanged event.

But the label values is not changing. it is still showing the old value "abc". what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To change other controls during the PageIndexChanged event, you might need to disable callbacks (see the ASPxGridView.EnableCallBacks property) and place both the text box and grid control onto the UpdatePanel.

Alternatively, you can do it on the client-side with javascript if you want to keep callbacks enabled. There's a sample project attached here:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q201214.aspx